# CUDA Cooperative Groups

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm using a Pascal GPU for synchronizing all blocks without performing multiple pass in the kernel. However, I'm not sure if I understand it well. In my case, I have a total of 117000 elements to be processed. Using a block size of 512 threads, it requires about 228 blocks. When I try to run the kernel, it says me that the number of blocks is high:

```
CUDA error at ../SW/SmithWatermanGPU.cu:122 code=82(cudaErrorCooperativeLaunchTooLarge) "cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)SWProc, blocks, NUM_THREADS_BLOCK, params)"
```

I understand that I cannot load all these blocks using cooperative groups.  Is that right?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that I cannot load all these blocks using cooperative
>   groups. Is that right?

Yes.

There are occupancy restrictions which you must respect for a cooperative launch to succeed. This is discussed in detail in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization-cg). With 512 threads per block, you will be limited to a maximum of 4 blocks per SM, and the largest Pascal GPU I am aware of has 56 SM, meaning the upper bound would be 224 blocks, and might be less depending on your GPU and kernel resource requirements.

Comment: To my recollection, cc 6.0 has more smaller SMX, like 56.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET: Indeed you are correct. I'll fix the answer.